# In firefox works normally but in IE and chrome update after finished script

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I want make script with async=false ajax to make some controls and save. 
And I want to show user progress of this. But in IE and chrome update Label1 after finish whole script. Firefox work fine. Have anyone some idea what I did wrong??

Thanks for help.

**mydata.php**

```
if ($_POST['oper']=='wait')
 {
  sleep(2);
 }
```

**CODE**

```
function myFunc()
 {
  $.ajax({ type: 'POST',cache: false, url: 'mydata.php', data: {oper: 'wait'}, dataType: 'json', async: false});
  $('#Label1').html('1');
  $.ajax({ type: 'POST',cache: false, url: 'mydata.php', data: {oper: 'wait'}, dataType: 'json', async: false});
  $('#Label1').html('2');
  $.ajax({ type: 'POST',cache: false, url: 'mydata.php', data: {oper: 'wait'}, dataType: 'json', async: false});
  $('#Label1').html('3');
  }




 <span name='Label1' id='Label1'>XXX</span><button onclick='myFunc()'>Save</button>
```

Comment: firefox will interpret the code fine, but other browser engines won't. you can try to delay the next ajax some milli seconds so that you can then see the effects on UI as well.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I do that? I try change label with settimeout but IE and chrome must finish script and after that they play settimeout. If U have idea how force him too wait for a while and redraw that label it will be nice.

Comment: Async: false? why? Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sry for that post, U all right. **async=false is deprecated** and I must find **another way**. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunc()
{
  $.ajax({ type: 'POST',cache: false, url: 'mydata.php', data: {oper: 'wait'}, dataType: 'json', async: false});
  $('#Label1').delay('1000').html('1');
  $.ajax({ type: 'POST',cache: false, url: 'mydata.php', data: {oper: 'wait'}, dataType: 'json', async: false});
  $('#Label1').delay('1000').html('2');
  $.ajax({ type: 'POST',cache: false, url: 'mydata.php', data: {oper: 'wait'}, dataType: 'json', async: false});
  $('#Label1').delay('1000').html('3');
  }
```

But I would recommend you to use Ajax Success/Complete function instead of waiting for the ajax to fully complete.

***Something like this:***

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST', cache: false, url: 'mydata.php', data: {oper: 'wait'}, dataType: 'json', async: false, success: function() { /* Do whatever you want here when your ajax has been successful. */}, error: function() { /* Here you can handle the errors thrown by ajax */ alert(e);}, complete: function() { /* Put the code here what you want to run irrespective of success or error. */ }})
```

Comment: For "wait" is required async = true :)

Comment: Sry for that post, U all right. async=false is deprecated and I must find another way. Thanks for help.